# Code not executing in img.onload

Tags: javascript, image, asynchronous

`alert('loaded');` is never executed in the first code snippet.
The only difference between the 2 code snippets is `alert('setting src..');` is commented out in first example, but left in the 2nd example.
Why is `alert('loaded');` not executed in first example?

I have a html file, containing a form, when the form is submitted `Utils.imgExists()` is called.
`Utils.imgExists()` is declared in a JS file, included in the html document.

```
 <form action="anotherPage.html" method="get" onsubmit="return Utils.imgExists('http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/711375main_grail20121205_4x3_946-710.jpg')">
       <div id="imageInput">
           <input 
               type="text" 
               id="image" 
               name="image" 
               value="http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/711375main_grail20121205_4x3_946-710.jpg"
               title="Paste an image URL e.g http://server.com/path/to/image.jpg"/>
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

`Utils.imgExists()` inside Utils.js:

```
var Utils = {
    imgExists: function(url){
        function imgExists(url, callback) {
            alert('in imgExists');

            var img = new Image();

            img.onerror = function() {
                alert('error');
                callback(false);
            };

            img.onload = function () {
                alert('loaded');
                callback(true);
            };

            img.src = url;
            //alert('setting src..');
        }

        function checkImage(exists) {
            alert("Image exists: " + exists);
        }

        imgExists('http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/711375main_grail20121205_4x3_946-710.jpg', checkImage);
    }
};
```

This is the second example:

```
var Utils = {
    imgExists: function(url){
        function imgExists(url, callback) {
            alert('in imgExists');

            var img = new Image();

            img.onerror = function() {
                alert('error');
                callback(false);
            };

            img.onload = function () {
                alert('loaded');
                callback(true);
            };

            img.src = url;
            alert('setting src..');
        }

        function checkImage(exists) {
            alert("Image exists: " + exists);
        }

        imgExists('http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/711375main_grail20121205_4x3_946-710.jpg', checkImage);
    }
};
```

Comment: Where are you calling this?

Comment: You are likely binding to `onload` after the image has been loaded, but we'd need to see where you are calling `imgExists`

Comment: Add some `console.log's` in the onerror and onload and so on. Mayby that gives you a better idea of what's happening.

Comment: Also, can you create an [JSFiddel](http://www.jsfiddle.net), so that we can try and understand it better

Comment: is "loaded" getting called in second example????

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/donce17/5udtC/5596/ it looks like all your alert is alerting

Comment: added html where JS function is called. Note: The html document is never checked for `loaded` event e.g `$(document).ready(function()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is loading based on jsfiddle provided by @nzn: http://jsfiddle.net/donce17/5udtC/5596/

```
function imgExists(url, callback) {
    alert('in imgExists');

    var img = new Image();

    img.onerror = function() {
        alert('error');
        callback(false);
    };

    img.onload = function () {
        alert('loaded');
        callback(true);
    };

    img.src = url;
    //alert('setting src..');
}

function checkImage(exists) {
    alert("Image exists: " + exists);
}

imgExists('http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/711375main_grail20121205_4x3_946-710.jpg', checkImage);
```